# How to use Virtus with Sequel or ROM?

Tags: ruby, sequel, ruby-datamapper

I've started using DataMapper in my project, then I've found out that it is actually a frozen project. DataMapper 2.0 moved to [ROM (Ruby Object Mapper)](http://rom-rb.org/), however the Property API from DataMapper was extracted to [Virtus](http://solnic.eu/2011/06/06/virtus-attributes-for-your-plain-ruby-objects.html) project.

What I need is to keep definition of particular class in one place (relationship + attributes) and I cannot allow to keep model in *schema definition* prior to the class as it breaks low level requirements for the project. I need to map classes to model (way of persistence), not model to classes.

So, I start wonder if there is any way to glue Virtus and Sequel or ROM together, to have attributes definitions in same class declaration and get the database schema automatically as I would in DataMapper. I am looking at direction how can I hook to Virtus machinery and add schema to model by `DB.create_table()` (Sequel)... or something similar.

Please avoid answers and comments that are not hints how to do that. If it is not possible, I just remove DataMapper and abandon ORM then and instead I will create repository of marshaled objects.